# sharing an url for collaborative work using socket.io in node.js

Tags: node.js, url, express, socket.io

I'm working on multiuser drawing app using node.js and socket.io

I'm using express web framework over node.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http");
var hoganex = require('hogan-express');
var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app)
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var routes = require('./routes');

 var app = express({
   views: path.join(__dirname, 'views')
 });
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('layout', 'layout.html');
app.engine('html', hoganex);
app.get('/test', routes.index);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//code for collaboration goes here using socket.on and other methods for sending...
});
```

I want to do something similar to what [**etherpad**](http://etherpad.org/) and [**togetherjs**](https://togetherjs.com/) have done. Whenever a user visits the webapp, a fresh instance of that app is provided to him, now he can share some sort of manipulated or any other random generation of url, with which he can connect other users/peers so that they all can collaborate their work, in my case collaborative drawing.

So the thing is how to carry this out. Rendering the same `index` page to every fresh incoming user and then providing him the feature of sharing some sort of url so that users pertaining to that particular url would be able to collaborate their work using sockrt.io and the procedure continues for other `n` users collaborating their work with other `m` users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Someone Elses

You should have a look at [Etherdraw](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/draw). It does exactly what you describe using Node.js and socket.io.

### Roll Your Own

1. When a user goes to your site, lets call it draw.yoursite.com, create a new unique room_id in a datastore and send the user to a blank canvas. When the user draws, send the drawing data (namely, type of line, line start (x,y), line end (x,y)) via socket.io to server. The data is stored in the datastore and published to all users who are subscribed to that room (pub/sub).
2. When a new user requests a room (draw.yoursite.com/[room_id]), the datastore is queried. (Etherdraw stores data in JSON format in a flatfile by default, but it is recommended to use something like MongoDB for anything other than testing.)
3. If the requested room already exists, send back the data for that room. The drawings are stored in the datastore as (x,y) coordinates with attributes describing how to connect the points (ie straight line, bold, arced, etc..).

Comment: Yes I have gone through this but I didn't get how they manage to allow that functionality